# How to use Forge Design Automation without ngrok?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to go through the "Modify your Models" example from https://learnforge.autodesk.io/

Unfortunately *ngrok* is not working in our corporate network. If I try to run any of the command below

```
ngrok http 3000 -host-header="localhost:3000"
ngrok http 80
```

The only thing I get is:

```
listen tcp 127.0.0.1:4049: socket: An invalid argument was supplied.
```

and the tunneling is not working.

Is there any other option available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try running ngrok in admin mode, and ngrok is one of the many ways to listen to webhooks.

If ngrok is prevented on corporate networks, you can try https://webhook.site/#!/db7c735c-bcb8-49c8-8e5d-51ec8d5937ad, and pass the link to the app.

Comment: Thanks @Madhukar, I don't have admin rights on this computer, so it wouldn't be practical.
However I can see the webhook coming in webhook.site so I can see that it works. But I suppose there is no way to link this back to the local webserver.

Comment: Tried to run it as admin and it I get the following errors as it tries to connect:
Session Status: reconnecting (x509: certificate signed by unknow authority)
Session Status: reconnecting (resolved tunnel.us.ngrok.com has no records)

Comment: This happens when proxy blocks ngrok domain - refer  [issue418](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/418#issuecomment-370205078)
you need to creak a ngrok.yml with following
`root_cas: trusted`
refer [ngrok-fix](https://imgur.com/JknDo9A)

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala where should the yml file be placed? I've placed "ngrok" in /usr/bin/local folder so that I can run from any where based on the default $PATH

Comment: @Satyam - On Windows, it should placed relative to ngrok.exe, ngrok.exe should be able to find the yml, may be for unix systems, you can try placing in same path as ngrok.exe.

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala my laptop is provided by office and IT team has disabled something related to installing X509 certificates. they don't disable it. how to handle it now?